# kivy: Animated elements reset position when ScrollView is scrolled

Tags: kivy

I have a vertically scrollable ScrollView, which contains a GridLayout, which contains a couple of Image elements (`from kivy.uix.image import Image`) animated with `kivy.animation`. The animations start as soon as the screen containing the ScrollView is created, moving the images to different positions. However, as soon as the screen is scrolled down, the images are restored to their original positions.

The images are created in python as specified below, and added to the GridLayout with `addWidget()`:

```
Image(source = filename, keep_ratio = False, allow_stretch = True, size_hint_y = None, height = self.image_height)
```

Is it possible to make the images retain the positions they acquired when the animations concluded, regardless of scrolling actions? Thank you.

Comment: Are the images defined in kv language with a reference to their parent position? And if they are in a grid, does that mean a GridLayout?

Comment: @inclement - made edits to the original post addressing those questions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, attempting to position a scrollable table (ie a gridlayout) inside a float layout at an arbitrary position. The scrolling action would reset the table position. I could work around this by binding a callback on `pos` to 'un-reset' the table position:

```
# grid layout for a table
self.tlayout = GridLayout(cols=2,rows=10,size_hint_x=0.96,pos_hint={'x':0.02,'y':0})
self.tlayout.bind(pos=self.set_pos)
self.tlayout.pos = [1,1] # initialize with a dummy value, so the change to [0,0] is picked up by the callback

# scrollview containing that table
self.slayout = ScrollView(self.tlayout,pos_hint={'x':0.00,'y':0}, \            do_scroll_y=True,do_scroll_x=False,bar_width=10,size_hint_y=None, \
bar_color = [.3,.3,.3,.9],bar_inactive_color=[0.3,0.3,0.3,.9],scroll_type=['content','bars'])
self.slayout.size_hint_x = 1

# float to contain the scrolled table
self.flayout = FloatLayout()
self.flayout.addwidget(self.slayout)

...

# callback to reset the position of the table, (based on the 
# size of the float layout container in this example but could
# be anything)
def set_pos(self):
    self.tlayout.pos = self.flayout.width * 0.02,0
```

but in some cases got a Too Many Iterations warning so that seemed like it wasn't entirely a correct idea. Eventually I found this in scrollview.py in lines 1135-1138:

```
# from 1.8.0, we now use a matrix by default, instead of moving the
# widget position behind. We set it here, but it will be a no-op most
# of the time.
vp.pos = 0, 0
```

I commented this out and my intended floating offset was now fixed, but have no idea if that could break something else.